# How to config maven home in jenkins with m2e(maven plugin)?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, m2eclipse

I installed m2e(maven plugin in eclipse) not install maven

when using jenkins, it needs config maven home

Where to config the maven home?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Jenkins have a Maven plugin which should be present by default. I suggest reading the documentation and examples.

Comment: ManageJenkins->ConfigSystem->Maven->Maven_HOME this place need config MAVEN,but I just have m2e plugin

Comment: its better to use MAVEN_HOME as build parameter.